# Customize Bootstrap 5 to use only only grid and buttons component?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I would like to use Bootstrap 5's grid system, buttons, and forms component only.

There used to be such an option in Bootstrap 3.4 but now I'm forced to use the bootstrap.min.css which is 195kb!! This is too large for the work I'm planning to do.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can customize with sass - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/optimize/ and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 5.2, you can use the Bootstrap CLI tool to build a customized version of Bootstrap that only includes the components and styles related to modals.

Here are the steps to follow:

Install Node.js and npm if you haven't already, using the instructions on the official website: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Open a command prompt or terminal and install the Bootstrap CLI tool using the following command:

```
npm install -g bootstrap-cli
```

After installing the Bootstrap CLI tool, you can use it to build a customized version of Bootstrap. For example, to build a version of Bootstrap with modals, run the following command in the folder of your project:

```
bootstrap build --modal
```

After building the customized version of Bootstrap, you will find the files in the dist folder of your project. This folder will contain the CSS and JS files related to modals.